Client cannot receive data from server C# (Websocket Sharp)
I'm trying to make a simple WinForms chat app with WebSockets, and I've got to the point where I can send data to the server from the Client, but the server cannot receive it.
Here is the server code:
public class Chat : WebSocketBehavior
{
    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        Send(e.Data);
    } 
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebSocketServer wss = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8080");
    wss.AddWebSocketService<Chat>("/Chat");
    wss.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server started on: ws://localhost:8080/Chat!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    wss.Stop();
}

Here is the client code:
WebSocket ws = new WebSocket(KChat.IP);

private void chat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ws.Connect();
        ws.Send("Connected! ");
        ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;
    

}

private void Ws_OnMessage(object? sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = e.Data;

}
//other code

and here is the client side button, that sends the info to the server:
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ws.Send(textBox1.Text);
     textBox1.Clear();
 }

Any idea why this happens?
I have tried to make it work, but I've got no luck.

where do you get WebSocketServer from? Is it a Nuget package?

The OnStart is not registering the OnMessage Event.  See https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/Server/WebSocketBehavior.cs#L575
